# Problem with Creality v1.1.4 (Ender 3 Pro) and BLTOUCH v3.0 (removed C7 capacitor)

Tags: creality-ender-3, bltouch

I followed this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3TTuisjmbmY&t=624s) on how to set up **BLTOUCH v3.0 with my Ender 3 Pro**. (v1.1.4 motherboard)

I even **removed C7 capacitor** on Z axes. And **no luck**. My BLTouch probe is working, it turns on with the Ender and testing is fine. But it doesn't stop the printer on Z axis while auto homing.

Firmware is from firmware.th3dstudio.com

Any ideas? Any advice is highly appreciated.

My configuration.h file: https://paste.ofcode.org/Z4kKiGwYXC6yQ698t9uaeY

My configuration_backend.h file: https://paste.ofcode.org/34tuX4mG3Ph57jSnT8YByi3

Comment: I'm no personal fan (although many other people swear by it) of all those Marlin derivative firmware solutions that try to encapsulate all the printer configurations. These lag behind the original sources and maintaining them and keeping it to work properly for all printers is quite a challenge. If I were you I would use the original Marlin sources and work from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the probe works, but not on auto homing, it could be that the Z endstop/probe wires are incorrectly wired.

From ["The complete BLTouch/3DTouch guide for Creality printers (CR-10/s,Ender 2,Ender 3) for Auto Bed Leveling UPDATED"](https://cdn.thingiverse.com/assets/67/42/7a/bf/ad/v3_Fixed_Creality_BLTOUCH_Guide.pdf) can be read:

> If you connect your bltouch and when auto homing the sensor doesn’t register
>   & the z axis keeps dropping pressing into your bed, turn your printer off,
>   disconnect the power and invert the black and white connectors in the z limit
>   switch header (put black where white was, put white where black was).

This can also be found in [this Marlin issue tracker](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/issues/12948):

> The Problem was the polarity of the sensor wires was reversed.

If [reversing the polarity does not work](https://www.reddit.com/r/ender3/comments/eee23n/ender_3_bltouch_v3_probe_not_stopping_for_z_axis/), move to the original Marlin firmware.

Comment: Thanks, the real problem was bad wires. Not the wiring, but wires. I just put new ones and everything works fine!